# Why i can't see my js file from browser - tomcat 7

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tomcat, mapping

I deployed my ROOT.war to Tomcat webapps folder. When I'm writing in a web browser address www.exampleaddress.com I can see index.jsp file.

But in the same folder is file.js. I Would like to see it when I write address: www.exampleaddress.com/file.js but now i can see only empty white page without any code. Any ideas?

Comment: Check that file is there in tomcat webapps ROOT directory

Comment: /webapps/ROOT/
HERE IS: /META-INF/, /WEB-INF/, index.jsp and script.js

Comment: Not in META-INF . Check your fil is there where your index.jsp file is located

Comment: jsp file and js file are in ROOT/ Catalog. Problem is that index.jsp are visible from bowser but js file not.

Comment: Are you importing your JS file in your JSP page?

Comment: No. i don't need it. I just wonna get this js file from outside address www.some.com/file.js

Comment: <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  to web.xml and solved!

Answer (score 1):

You can't place JS files or any publicly accessible data inside the WEB-INF folder. You need a JS folder in the same directory as your WEB-INF folder and that is where you place them. The same goes for your .css files and your images. None of that can be seen from inside WEB-INF.

/WebApp/CSS/index.css

/WebApp/JS/index.js

/WebApp/WEB-INF/index.jsp

/WebApp/Images/logo.png